# How to handle this external php login form for phpbb through ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phpbb

Recently converted my page to jquery/ajax to have a truly dynamic page. Some of my PHP functions are suffering as a result. This is the latest.

Here is my PHP for handling the login

```
<?php
if($user->data['is_registered'])
{
   //user is logged in
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Welcome back ';
    print $user->data['username'];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'You have ' . $user->data['user_unread_privmsg'] . ' unread <a href="./forum/ucp.php?i=pm&folder=inbox">message(s)</a>';
    echo '</h3><h4><a title="See You Later" href="' . append_sid("{$phpbb_root_path}ucp.$phpEx", 'mode=logout', true, $user->session_id). '">Log out</a></h4>';
}
else{
     //user is not logged in 
   echo '
       <form method="post" action="forum/ucp.php?mode=login">
         <label for="username">
            Username:
         </label>
         <input type="text" name="username" id="username" size="16" />
         <label for="password">
            Password:
         </label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" size="16" />
         <label for="autologin">
            Remember?:
         </label>
         <input type="checkbox" name="autologin" id="autologin"  />
         <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="../" />
         <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="login" id="login" />
         <a title="Register" href="forum/ucp.php?mode=register">
         <br>
          Register
         </a>
      </form>

        ';
}
?>
```

And the script.

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // handle the login form through ajax for phpbb
    $(document).on('submit', '#login', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var url= $(this).attr('action');
    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'HTML',
        data: new FormData(this),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I've tried running the jquery as both standalone, and echoing it in before and after in the PHP. I've tried removing all the hidden redirects as well, but this unfortunately does just what it sounds like, logs in and does nothing at all.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You have attached your `submit` handler to the button. The button has no `submit` event, no form data and no `action` attribute, so your code will not run.

You need to attach the event handler to the form instead.

If you have multiple forms, you can add an id to identify it:

```
<form method="post" action="forum/ucp.php?mode=login" id="loginForm">
```

And then in your javascript:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#loginForm', function(event) {
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought I had to try and apply it to the exact function I was using (in this case the submit button), so that's a great tip thanks. Still no change in the behaviour though, either running the script itself or echoing it in.

Comment: @Rogerjwilkinson You need to add more details, what exactly is happening, which alerts / console.log's do you see?